# Concatendate n dataframes by index

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to union several `pd.DataFrames` along the column axis, using the index to remove duplicates (A and B are from the same source "table" filterd by different predicates and I'm tring to recombine).

```
A = pd.DataFrame({"values": [1, 2]}, pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(1,1),(1,2)], names=('l1', 'l2')))
B = pd.DataFrame({"values": [2, 3, 2]}, pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(1,2),(2,1),(2,2)], names=('l1', 'l2')))
```

`pd.concat([A,B]).drop_duplicates()` fails since it ignores the index and de-dups on the values so it removed index item (2,2)

`pd.concat([A.reset_index(),B.reset_index()]).drop_duplicates(subset=('l1', 'l2')).set_index(['l1', 'l2'])` does what I want, but I feel like there should be a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may do a simple `concat` and filter out dups by using `index.duplicated`

```
df1 = pd.concat([A,B])
df1[~df1.index.duplicated()]

Out[123]:
       values
l1 l2
1  1        1
   2        2
2  1        3
   2        2
```

Comment: Thanks, that's much cleaner and appears quite a bit quicker